# Unigram Analysis with Scikit Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I am trying to do some analysis on unigrams in Sci Kit Learn. I created files in svmlight format and tried to run `MultinomialNB() KNeighborsClassifier() and SVC()`. We I first tried to do that with unigrams I got a X training dimension error presumably because the only unigrams that are included in a given example are the ones that show up in the training fit there. I tried creating svmlight format training files that include place holders for every seen unigram in the corpus even those not in that given example.

The problem is that inflated the training files from 3 MB to 300 MB. This caused memory errors for sklearn loading the files. Is there a way to get around the dimension mismatches or memory overflows.

```
X_train, y_train= load_svmlight_file(trainFile)
x_test, y_test = load_svmlight_file(testFile)
try:
    clf = MultinomialNB()
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    preds = clf.predict(x_test)
    print('Input data:  ' + trainFile.split('.')[0])
    print('naive_bayes')
    print('accuracy: ' + str(accuracy_score(y_test, preds)))
    if 1 in preds:
        print('precision: ' + str(precision_score(y_test, preds)))
        print('recall: ' + str(recall_score(y_test, preds)))
except Exception as inst:
    print 'fail in NB  ' + 'Input data:  ' + trainFile.split('.')[0]
    print str(inst)
    pass
```

2828 test examples and 1212 test examples with 18000 distinct unigrams

EDIT  I tried to use the `sklearn CountVectorizer` but I am still getting the memory issues. Is this the best way to do this?

```
def fileLoadForPipeline(trainSetFile, valSetFile):
    with open(trainSetFile) as json_file:
    tdata = json.load(json_file)
with open(valSetFile) as json_file:
    vdata = json.load(json_file)
x_train = []
x_val = []
y_train = []
y_val = []
for t in tdata:
    x_train.append(t['request_text'])
    y_train.append(t['requester_received_pizza'])
for v in vdata:
    x_val.append(t['request_text'])
    y_val.append(t['requester_received_pizza'])
return x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val

def buildPipeline(trainset, valset, norm):
x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val = fileLoadForPipeline(trainset, valset)
bigram_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2), token_pattern=ur'\b\w+\b', min_df=1)
xT = bigram_vectorizer.fit_transform(x_train).toarray()
xV = bigram_vectorizer.fit_transform(x_val).toarray()
if norm:
    transformer = TfidfTransformer()
    xT = transformer.fit_transform(xT)
    xV = transformer.fit_transform(xV)
results = []
for clf, name in ((Perceptron(n_iter=50), "Perceptron"),
              (KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=40), "kNN"), (MultinomialNB), (MultinomialNB(alpha=.01),'MultinomialNB'),
              (BernoulliNB(alpha=.1),'BernoulliNB'),(svm.SVC(class_weight='auto'),'svc')):
    print 80 * '='
    print name
    results.append(benchmark(clf))
```

Comment: Could you post the length and dimensions of X_train, y_train, x_test, and y_test along with the error you get?

Comment: I mean if you could print the dimensions in the code and post them here? Or do you get an error when assigning those arrays? and what's the error on the console?

Comment: using try...except in such code is unnecessary.

Comment: @user823743 Why is it unnecessary

Comment: Its unnecessary because there are no valid exceptions to catch. Either the classifier fails most probably because your data dimensions are not consistent or it succeeds. Your data is not too big to cause a problem. If there is a problem because of converting files to svmlight format, I don't know much about it.

Comment: This tutorial may be of use: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html Excerpt: "Text preprocessing, tokenizing and filtering of stopwords are all included in `CountVectorizer`, which builds a dictionary of features and transforms documents to feature vectors"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using scikit-learn's [`CountVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) which will do the feature extraction on raw text for you. Most importantly, the method `fit_transform` called on a set of training examples will automatically do the Bag of Words unigram transformation, where it keeps track of all `n` unique words found in the training corpus, and converts each document into an array of length `n` whose features can be either discrete word counts or binary presence features (depending on the `binary` option). The great thing about `CountVectorizer` is that it stores data in numpy sparse matrix format, which makes it very memory efficient, and should be able to solve any memory problems you're having.

You can then call `transform` on future testing examples, and it will do conversion like normal.

This should also help solve any dimensionality issues, as `CountVectorizer`'s job is to regularize everything. Specific information on usage here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#common-vectorizer-usage

An added benefit of this is that you can combine this vectorizer with a classifier using a [`Pipeline`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html) to make fitting and testing more convenient.

Comment: I tried this and attempted to fix it in the above code. Am I doing it right?